# Strikethrough for Label, getting the Text subnode of a Label using lookup

Tags: css, javafx

I have multiple identical Task objects in a VBox, I am attempting to format the text of a Label of certain tasks with a strikethrough. From what I know, this can only be done on the text subnode of the Label.

The below code returns me a null pointer:

```
label.lookup(".text");
```

Yet, I can achieve my formatting of the strikethrough with this line in CSS:

```
#label .text {
    -fx-strikethrough: true;
}
```

Is there a way to achieve the strikethrough effect using the inline code method?Or is there any workaround using CSS? Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with the CSS approach?

Comment: I'm intending to create multiple objects with this label, but only format some of them as strikethrough. Using CSS applies the strikethrough for the labels of all objects.

Comment: So just add a style class to the labels you want to have a strikethrough.... If you [edit] your question to more fully describe what you're trying to achieve, it might be easier to give you a complete answer. (The lookup should work too, but lookups are not very robust. You haven't provided any context as to when you all it.)

Comment: Okay noted, will try out your suggestion. I will edit the question to include more details if I still have difficulties. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The issue with my implementation was that I was fixated with using a common CSS stylesheet for all of the Task objects.  The most simple solution was to access the text subnode in the Label as shown above, and create multiple stylesheets for each task according to whether the style is required or not:

```
if(isStrikethrough) {
    label.getStylesheets.addAll(getClass().getResource("Strikethrough.css").toExternalForm());
} else {
    label.getStylesheets.addAll(getClass().getResource("NoStrikethrough.css").toExternalForm());
}
```

Many thanks to James_D for helping me with such an amateur question, haha

Comment: It's probably easier to use different style classes for the labels, but a single stylesheet. You might also consider a [CSS `PseudoClass`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/css/PseudoClass.html) for this. [Here](https://gist.github.com/james-d/846eb9ff72bd66fdd955) is an example using pseudoclasses.

Comment: wow, didn't know that was possible. Thanks for the great example!